# Processing Video library and code used in 1.5.1 not compatible with 3.0

Tags: video, processing, compatibility

Compiling a code for my college project, I realized I had been using processing 1.5.1 as it ran the most smoothly and displayed no QuicktimeSTD errors in my laptop. (Took the initial code from  Open Processing)

Once I finished the code I realized that processing 2.0 and processing 3.0 gives a much better frame rate to work with and increases the efficiency of the program.
But now I am not able to make it compatible with the latest version of processing. I have tried reinstalling the libraries a couple of times.
The two libraries that are being used are Video and Core

Running the code on Processing 3.0 shows me this error on this line:
NoSuchMethodError: You may be using a library that's incompatible with this version of Processing

```
capture = new Capture(this, 800, 600, 30);
```

I would really appreciate if someone could just help me run the code below in processing 3.0 or in the worst case processing 2.0

The code: http://pastebin.com/uRqbVHK9

The core.jar file (to be put in the code folder): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8B1cIEvfYOAdjNxc2ZlMXhaS1U

Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add Video library (menu Sketch, Import Library), and your code should reference it:

[image]

```
import processing.video.*;

...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/15), the Video library should work okay in Processing 3.

I would try uninstalling all versions of Processing. Make sure all of the files are deleted, especially the library files. Then install the latest version of Processing 3, and finally install the Video library through the sketch > add library menu of the Processing editor.

Comment: Took a friends laptop and tried this but it doesnt work. 
Its a code compatibility problem. Have tried the same code in numerous laptops but nothing works.
tried doing what you showed but the same problem persists